# Manipulating Perlin noise output to create different ore veins in different depths

Tags: java, android, maps, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I am developing a simple project using Java, for Android. It is a side-scroller with a procedurally generated, infinite world. Most of the generation will be working on underground but I expect the same principles would apply to features that would be above the ground.

I have 2 coordinates. **X** goes Left-Right and **Y** goes Up-Down. I have managed to generate a density map using Perlin. What I do is looping through X and Y values, putting them in a noise function, and evaluating the resulting float to decide whether to place a specific tile or not. I have successfully created a uniform tile distribution. However I need something a bit more specialized.

You see, in order to make this interesting, I need to place various resources (Coal, Iron, Silver, Gold) as well as monster spawns in the map. I am thinking that it would be more realistic to place different resources in different **depth levels**. So for example, I need coal to appear between Y = -20 and Y = -50, Iron between -40 and -100, ogre spawners between -40 and -300 etc.

However, if I set these boundaries with a simple if statement like:

```
if (y<-20 && y>-50) {
    // Generate coal
    noise = perlin.getnoise(x,y,7);
    if (noise>=threshold) map.put(x,y,TILE_TYPE_COAL);
}
if (y<-40 && y>-100) {
    // Generate iron
    noise = perlin.getnoise(x,y,7);
    if (noise>=threshold) map.put(x,y,TILE_TYPE_IRON);
}
```

This generates sharp edges between those boundaries, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJGLk.jpg

I need the noise to somehow generate resources that, when digging down, would **gradually** appear more often, and then **gradually** less so. Ease in and ease out.

For example, if I set the boundaries for coal to be between -20 and -50, most of the coal should appear in the middle of this ribbon, -35, while it should appear less in -20 and -50 levels. Perhaps I need a Gaussian distribution? I don't know where to start.

To put the question in a more mathematical form:

*How do I manipulate the output of a Perlin noise function depending on one of the inputs (Y) in a non-abrupt, natural way, in order to gradually increase or decrease density for specific ranges of Y?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is to modify the threshold value based on the height.

```
if (noise>=threshold) map.put(x,y,TILE_TYPE_COAL);
```

This means that where `threshold` is small you'll be more likely to place coal, and where `threshold` is large, less likely to place it.  So, you should be able to get a gradient in coal density by setting `threshold` as a function of `y`, in such a way that the threshold is high near the boundaries of the coal area, and low in the middle.  Assuming your noise function outputs values from 0 to 1, you could try something like this:

```
ribbonDist = (y - ribbonCenter) / ribbonRadius;
threshold = 1.0 - coalOverallDensity * min(ribbonDist*ribbonDist, 1.0);
```

Here `coalOverallDensity` is a factor controlling how much coal there is overall, `ribbonCenter` is the y-value at the center of the ribbon (-35 in your example) and `ribbonRadius` is the distance from the center to the edge of the ribbon (15 in your example).  You can see a graph of this function and adjust the parameters [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ifywfpxri1).

I chose a quadratic function (`ribbonDist*ribbonDist`), but you could also use other options like a triangle function or a Gaussian to get a different look, if desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot. When I used this the way it is, it created a ribbon (with noisy gradient) but no gaps in between. I have added 2 parameters (one multiplies the result, the other is added) With all these variables, I can tweak the result as I see fit, and I was able to create something that was believable. Thank you